# Android Studio change LinearLayout size

Tags: android, size, android-linearlayout

I would like to change the size of my linear layout in my program not in the xml file itself. I'm a beginner and also would like to declare my variable outside a method (public) and initialize it in the method, like I did it with EditText and the LinearLayout.

I tried it that way, but it says:

```
Error:(47, 81) error: incompatible types: android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams cannot be converted to android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams
```

But I dont know what to do with this error :(

My Code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


    public EditText input_chat;
    public LinearLayout layout_chat_input;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout_chat_input_params;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onCreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        input_chat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_chat);
        layout_chat_input = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_chat_input);
        layout_chat_input_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(layout_chat_input.getLayoutParams());

        input_chat.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if (input_chat.getLineCount() > 0 && input_chat.getLineCount() < 5)
                {

                    layout_chat_input_params = layout_chat_input.getLayoutParams();
                    layout_chat_input.setLayoutParams();
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

    if (input_chat.getLineCount() > 0 && input_chat.getLineCount() < 5){
        layout_chat_input.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

OR

```
layout_chat_input.setLayoutParams(layout_chat_input_params);
```